# Script to add string before the first column of a file

Tags: awk, text

I have the following file:

```
ID      firstname        lastname
1       John             Wilkens
2       Andrea           Smith
```

I would like to add in the ID field before the numbers the following string for each row in the file: "del_", so the output would look like this:

```
ID          firstname        lastname
del_1       John             Wilkens
del_2       Andrea           Smith
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Using standard `sed` to do the same operation:

```bsh
sed '2,$ s/^/del_/' file
```

This applies a substitution (`s///`) to all lines between line two and the end of the file, inclusively (the range `2,$`).  The substitution simply inserts the string `del_` at the very start of each addressed line.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{print (NR>1 ? "del_" : "") $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -lpe '$_ = "del_" . $_ if $. > 1' data
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` variant:

```
awk 'NR>1{ sub(//, "del_") }1' infile
```